# $I - AB$ is surjective if and only if $I - B A$ is surjective.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $X$ be a linear space and let $A, B : X \rightarrow X$ be linear maps.
There are two claims that I am trying to show:

Claim 1: $I - AB$ is injective if and only if $I - B A$ is injective;

Claim 2: $I - AB$ is surjective if and only if $I - B A$ is surjective.

I have been able to show claim 1 and now am working on claim 2. It is clear to me that if $X$ is a finite dimensional linear space then claim 2 holds immediately from claim 1. I need help when $X$ is not finite.

Comment: It would be good to mention how and why you need help: what did you try? What went wrong? Etc.

Comment: I am studying for an exam and this is a practice problem. In terms of what I tried. I tried proving first that if $I-AB$ is onto then $I-BA$ is onto. If I start by definition, I know that for all $y \in X$ there exists and $x \in X$ such that $(I-AB)x = y$. Don't know what to do from here.

Comment: There is a general fact that if $I-AB$ is bijective so is $I-BA.$ Perhaps this helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume $1-AB$ is surjective.

**Hints:**

1. Show that the image of $B$ lies in the image of $1- BA$.
2. Write $v = (1-BA)v + BAv$.